# Creating a function that replace a letter with a line break

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to create a function that replace some specific character by a line break.

I'm fetching the data from my API but i'm always return `[object Object]`

my function is write like so:

```
  const includeFunction = (data) => {
const linebreak = React.createElement('br')
return data.replace("lb182", linebreak)
  }


          <ArticleComponent
            description={includeFunction(job.description)}

};
```

and i pass it to the render:

```
 description={includeFunction(job.description)}
```

any ideas how to replace characters with a linebreak ?

Comment: How are you actually rendering stuff? You should only do the element creation inside a render / during a component lifecycle

Comment: I got it to work if i replace with another word like 'Hello' but not with a dom element like a line break

Comment: You didn't answer my question... How are you actually rendering the content? What's your render method look like?

Comment: The printout you are seeing is the string representation of an object. You need to actually render the element or maybe approach it with a different method. Hard to know how to help without the code and also what the data looks like

Comment: Try to use regex instead a String in the function replace

Comment: What is the render of `ArticleComponent`, what I meant was the component trying to actually render the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be in your placing React elements into a string. You could instead have the funtion return an array with the strings and linebreaks. For example:

```
function replaceBreaks(data){
    const stringAsArr = data.split("lb182").map(str => [str, <br />]).flat();
    stringAsArr.pop();
    return stringAsArr;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it make total sense